# How do I check if I set +x (executable flag) on a file on GitHub?

Tags: github

Is there something on the GitHub interface that can distinguish if I `chmod +x`'d a file? If not readily visible, is there something I can easily do on a phone/non-dev-workstation to find out?

If the file wasn't modified a bunch (i.e. you wouldn't need to sift through a bunch of commits) you can go to a commit URL, add ".patch" to the end and look at the mode there.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can come up with is:

- Find the file in your source tree on GitHub, click on it.
- In the source header that shows number of lines and file size, "Executable File" will be displayed on the left of that header, if it is set to be executable.

... obviously, this doesn't show what specific file bits are turned on, but it does fit your minimum use case.

Comment: Hail to the fastest one... :)

Answer (score 3):

On the Github web interface there is the indication of executable file in the top left corner of the text box with the source:

[image]